# How to call a JPanel from another class

Tags: methods, jframe, jpanel

I have a JPanel with a JButton added to it in one class. I have a JFrame in another class, and a method that lets you get the JPanel from the second class. When I set the JFrame's contentpane to the JPanel, its black, however if I put the JFrame in the JPanel class, then it works properly. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Class one:

```
public class one {
private static JPanel p = new JPanel();

public one() {

    p.setVisible(true);
    p.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3, 25, 25));

    JButton b = new JButton("Testing");
    b.setBounds(60, 60, 100, 100);
    b.setVisible(true);



    p.add(b);


}
public static JPanel getP() {
    return p;
}
}
```

Class two:

```
public class two {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    f.setBounds(10, 10, 500, 500);
    f.setContentPane(one.getP());



    f.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing static keyword from one class, because you are doing jpanel operations in one's constructor. Remember constructor is called when you create new object from that class. As you made jpanel static and called the jpanel wihtout creating new one instance your jpanel operations are not executed. So your cade can be below:

```
public one() {

    p.setVisible(true);
    p.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3, 25, 25));

    JButton b = new JButton("Testing");
    b.setBounds(60, 60, 100, 100);
    b.setVisible(true);



    p.add(b);


}
public JPanel getP() {
    return p;
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    one o = new one();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    f.setBounds(10, 10, 500, 500);
    f.setContentPane(o.getP());



    f.setVisible(true);
}

}
```